# Batch file behaviour not as expected

Tags: python, batch-file, debugging, shelve

I have a pyw file that can store various keys and their values as shelf file and then take keys at time of calling file to copy the corresponding key to clipboard.
for example,

```
mcb.pyw save name 'name'
mcb.pyw name
```

will copy 'name' to clipboard using pyperclip. I made a batch file for this code and ran it using RUN prompt. However, I have noticed when I use strings that contain space, the command is not working as expected, while when I do the same from VScode, it works fine i.e.

```
   mcb.pyw save name 'name name'
```

will do nothing from RUN prompt while from VScode run will work fine.
I am not able to understand why batch file is behaving in this way.

The following is the code:

```
#! python3
# mcb.pyw - Saves andloads pieces of text to the clipboard
# Usage: py.exe mcb.pyw save <keyword> - Saves clipboard to keyword
#        py.exe mcb.pyw <keyword> - Loads keyword to clipboard
#        py.exe mcb.pyw list - Loads all keywords to clipboard

import shelve, pyperclip, sys
mcbShelf = shelve.open('mcb')
if len(sys.argv) == 4 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = sys.argv[3]
elif len(sys.argv)==2:
    if sys.argv[1].lower() == 'list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbShelf.keys())))
    elif sys.argv[1] in mcbShelf:
        pyperclip.copy(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]])
    elif sys.argv[1].lower() == 'delete':
        for i in mcbShelf:
            del mcbShelf[i]
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower == 'delete':
    del mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]]
mcbShelf.close()
```

I copied this from Automate the boring stuff with python, Ch8 and Appendix 2

Comment: maybe first use `pirnt()` to see what you get in `sys.argv` and `len(sys.argv)` - it is called `"print debuging"`. You may get different values or in different places then `[1]`. And maybe you will have to use `for`-loop to check all values in `sys.argv`. OR better use module `argparse` for this.

Comment: `cmd` parses the parameters and transfers four of them to `mcp.pyw`: `save`, `name`, `'name`, and  `name'`. To make a trying with spaces a single parameter, use doublequotes: `save name "name name"`. Of course, `mcp.pyw` then has to take care of the doublequotes.